# Install older versions of postgres(7.x or 8.x) in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I can only find installations for the latest stable version. Can someone provide me steps to install an older version of pg?

Thanks
Sithara

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (Especially 7.x)

Comment: Assigned to an oldie project which supports only postgres 7.x and 8.x !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed Postgresql 8.4 on Ubuntu 16.4 using the following:

```
#Requirements
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install bison

#Download postgres
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v8.4.22/postgresql-8.4.22.tar.gz
tar xfz postgresql-8.4.22.tar.gz
cd postgresql-8.4.22

#Installation
./configure
make
su
make install
adduser postgres
mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/data
chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
su - postgres
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb test
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql test
```

Look for documentation in order to install other version, in this case I've checked:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/install-short.html

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways is to install the required version of PostgreSQL from sources. Go to https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/. Download the required sources. And follow the instructions here 
[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/)
It shouldn't be difficult.

Probably you should consider running `sudo checkinstall` instead of `make install` in order to be able to uninstall the package in a clean way. Package 'checkinstall' must be installed separately.

Comment: I used sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4 postgresql-client-8.4 and it works. let me try your solution

Comment: @SitharaSuresh. Yes, you  can install version 8.4 or probably even 8.2 from the repository. But I am not sure about version 7.x and below. However, the sources are available for all versions of Postgresql.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html in which folder is this locates

Comment: @SitharaSuresh, the link above contains the documentation on how to build postgresql from sources. You should look at the installation procedure if you already got the sources.